# type in port declaration VHDL without using package

Tags: types, port, vhdl, state-machine

I have to write a hierarchical state machine, but I need to add the states to the ports. It won't let me since the `value_type` that I'm using is not declared yet, but I don't know how I can do this.

Here is my code:

```
entity statereg is
  port (
    Rst           : in  STD_LOGIC;
    Clk           : in  STD_LOGIC;
    TimeBase      : in  STD_LOGIC;
    StateDuration : in  integer range 0 to 15;
    next_state    : in  state_values;
    pres_state    : out state_values
  );
end statereg;

architecture Behavioral of statereg is
  type   state_values is (RED,REDAMBER,GREEN,AMBER);
  signal pres_state, next_state : state_values;
begin

end Behavioral;
```

Comment: I cannot see how this design will implement a hierarchical FSM. Moreover, by chaning the FSM pattern, you loose the FSM optimization of the synthesis tools.

Comment: The title constraint *without using package* isn't clear (all types such as `STD_LOGIC` or `integer` here are defined in packages) while we do find a design constraint *to write a hierarchical state machine*. The question isn't clear.

Comment: I've always been taught to only use std_logic and its vector variant for entity ports. Not sure how does this get implemented on hardware.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the enumeration type `state_values` in a package. By using the package, you can reference the types declared therein in your entity's port declaration.

Here the needed package:

```
package FSM_types is
  type state_values is (RED, REDAMBER, GREEN, AMBER);
end package;
```

Here the changed entity:

```
library IEEE;
use     IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;

use     work.FSM_types.all;

entity statereg is
  port (
    Clock      : in  std_logic;
    -- ...
    next_state : in  state_values;
    pres_state : out state_values
  );
end entity;
```